# Why are my layer-backed NSViews flashing?

Tags: cocoa, drawing, core-animation, calayer, nsview

I have a basic drawing app. I decided I wanted to have a CALayer backed NSView because, as I understand it, Layer Backed Views have performance benefits. Also, I noticed that it took care of redrawing the window during live window resizes. Either way, it sounded like a win-win. Here is my drawRect: method, which is triggered by, among other things, mouseDragged:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
if (firstDraw) { //Sets the background to white
    [[NSColor whiteColor]set];
    NSRectFill(rect);
    firstDraw = NO;
}
//strokeDict contains all the variable settings needed to stroke the path.
[(NSColor *)([self->strokeDict objectForKey:@"lineColor"]) set];
NSBezierPath *strokingPath = [[self->strokeDict objectForKey:@"bezierPath"] copy];
[strokingPath setLineWidth:[[self->strokeDict objectForKey:@"lineWidth"]floatValue]];
//setupPath sets the lineJoinStyle & Cap
[setupPath(strokingPath) stroke];
}
```

However, when run, I get the results shown below (albeit much faster). What on earth is going on?

[image: Don't stare too long]

Comment: Is `firstDraw` an instance variable? It looks like that change if state is not getting recognised. Try adding a `firstDraw` property to your class and use `self.firstDraw=NO` in your `drawRect`.

Comment: firstDraw is an ivar, just not a property. I'll make that clearer using self->var notation.

Comment: By the way, I found an interesting thread that may be related to this on cocoaBuilder.com- http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/192577-redraw-problem-with-layer-backed-view-in-scroll-view.html

Comment: How do you set up the CALayer backed NSView? Can you measure the performance benefit of having it layer-backed?

Comment: When you say that `drawRect:` is triggered by `mouseDragged:` you mean that in `mouseDragged:` you call `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]`, right? I don't know if you are calling `drawRect:` explicitly and don't know if calling it explicitly will cause the described behavior, just ruling out possible bug reason.

Comment: Yeah, I called setNeedsDisplay: